# How to access 'rel' from Links in header? Hypermedia link relations

Tags: javascript, json, hyperlink, hypermedia, json-server

I am using json server and axios

result from header

```
link: "<http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=1>; rel="first", <http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=2>; rel="next", <http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=5>; rel="last""
```

How can I use/access these data from link? There seems to be no information about how to parse or access this aside from github. I tried `link.rels[:last]` like from github but it doesnt work.

Comment: Did you check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735792/how-to-parse-link-header-from-github-api?

Comment: I had not seen that one. very helpful

Comment: @Catfish, any update on this?

Comment: @TarunLalwani The link from 31piy is very helpful. It has a library to simply do this. I also decided to use the octokit js lib which has methods for handling this https://github.com/octokit/rest.js

Answer (score 7):

Since JS is quite flexible you can simply use

```
data = 'link: "<http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=1>; rel="first", <http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=2>; rel="next", <http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=5>; rel="last""'

function parseData(data) {
    let arrData = data.split("link:")
    data = arrData.length == 2? arrData[1]: data;
    let parsed_data = {}

    arrData = data.split(",")

    for (d of arrData){
        linkInfo = /<([^>]+)>;\s+rel="([^"]+)"/ig.exec(d)

        parsed_data[linkInfo[2]]=linkInfo[1]
    }

    return parsed_data;
}

console.log(parseData(data))
```

The output is

```
{ first: 'http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=1',
  next: 'http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=2',
  last: 'http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=5' }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = 'link: "<http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=1>; rel="first", <http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=2>; rel="next", <http://localhost:3001/posts?_page=5>; rel="last""'

var linkRegex = /\<([^>]+)/g;
var relRegex = /rel="([^"]+)/g;
var linkArray = [];
var relArray = [];
var finalResult = {};
var temp;
while ((temp = linkRegex.exec(data)) != null) {
    linkArray.push(temp[1]);
}
while ((temp = relRegex.exec(data)) != null) {
    relArray.push(temp[1]);
}

finalResult = relArray.reduce((object, value, index) => {
    object[value] = linkArray[index];
    return object;
}, {});

console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: `var linkRegex = /\<([^;]+)/g;` should be `var linkRegex = /\<([^>]+)/g;`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes you are right I misspelled that Thanks.